# CSS Stretching div so that it stretch across screen

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I'm making a website and for the website, i'm using a navigation bar which is at the top. What I want is for the bar to be at the top of the page and it to be a separate color to the main page.
Here's my current code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Baloo Bhaina";
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#header {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 100%;
  padding-right: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Products</a>
  <a href="">Who we are</a>
  <a href="">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Some of the elements referenced in CSS are slightly irrelevant to the HTML, appoligies. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with this code? There are several possible issues, such as your header being set to `display: inline`, but it's difficult to help unless we know what you're seeing and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: remove display and padding to #header, then  add text-align if it is about centering links

Comment: Sorry with the padding-left: 100% thing. I was just testing out things and forgot to remove them. Seemed like a god idea at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fix nav part and content part is below with different `background-color`.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Baloo Bhaina";
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 250px;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#header {
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:99;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#content {
   width:100%;
   background:tomato;
   margin-top:45px;
   padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Products</a>
    <a href="">Who we are</a>
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
<br><br>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
 <br><br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
  <br><br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
     <br><br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
     <br><br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
     <br><br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
     <br><br>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus porro cupiditate aperiam esse eos ducimus consequatur labore magnam rerum. Ipsum eos corporis quo architecto voluptatum veniam, quas omnis modi ex!
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the header do

```
width:100%;
position:relative;
```

if it should always stay sticky on top

```
width:100%;
position:fixed;
```

also the header element shouldn't be display inline as mentioned in the comments. Paddings with 100% seems strange to me aswell

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't really deserve it's own post but since I can't comment, here I go:

First off, it's always helpful to have a resource at hand to aid you in your endeavors. In this case, I'd suggest something like [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) to help you out.

As for your example:

```
#header {
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    color: white;
    display: inline; /* if you're trying to get your <a> tags aligned, it's probably better to do it another way. */
    width: 100%; /* done */
    /*padding-left: 100%;
    padding-right: 100%; why would you even do this*/
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use css code only**

If you want to fix it at the top use `position:fixed` and `left` and `right` properties `0px`.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Baloo Bhaina";
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 250px;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#header {
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Products</a>
    <a href="">Who we are</a>
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good, the only thing is is that I would prefer if it would stretch out so it reached the end of the screen and not have a bit of "whitespace" bordering it and the rest of the website, if at makes sense.

Comment: i used `width:100%` if you need small change the width as you want. and if screen left side litbit space you can use `margin-left:0px;` or go for my second answer

Comment: Yeah, I figured out all I had to do was set `top` and `left` to 0px. Easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

to illustrate my comment :

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#header {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Products</a>
  <a href="">Who we are</a>
  <a href="">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    font-family: "Baloo Bhaina";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
}
#header {
background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

don't use position absolute, there is no need of #header { display: inline; width: 100%; }. remove these line also form code

Comment: Don't use comments to add info to your answer.  Edit your answer then delete your comment.